# Exclude directory from src/main/webapp from copying to target/app-SNAPSHOT directory

Tags: gwt, maven-2

I have project which builds .war file with maven. There is standard `src/main/webapp` directory. I have also some GWT code there which is compiled by GWT maven plugin. Sometimes I run GWT application from Eclipse, then GWT Eclipse plugin compiles it to `src/main/webapp/app.policy` (app.policy is name of my GWT module). This is OK.

```
app
|-src/main/webapp
| |-app.policy              (directory created by Eclipse GWT plugin)
|target
  |-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT        (directory created by Maven while building war)
  | |-app.policy            
  |-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

If `src/main/webapp/app.policy` does not exist, gwt-maven-plugin creates `target/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT/app.policy` and it is included in WAR. This is desired behavior.

The problem is if `src/main/webapp/app.policy` exists. Then it is copied to `target/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT/app.policy` and is not fully overwritten by what gwt-maven-plugin creates. Can I somehow exclude `src/main/webapp/app.policy` from being copied to `target/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT` directory?

I tried `<warSourceExcludes>`, but it doesn't work. It makes app.policy not go into .war, which is not what I want. I want it in .war, but I want it to be created by maven-gwt-plugin, not copied from `src/main/webapp`.

Answer (score -2):

Try to exclude the file from maven resources:

```
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>app.policy</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
```

If this works then you can add this configuration to a maven profile.